# My getBindingAdapterrPosition only returns -1

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to implement a feature on my application, where - if you click on a RecyclerView item - it opens up a dialog box for that item with a picture - kind of like InstaGram.

However, I am trying to make an onClickListener, where I get the position of the adapter. The goal is, that it reads what item I click on, so it can open up a dialog box for that specific item. But no matter what item in the recyclerview I click on, it returns the position as being -1.

Here is my code for it:

**UserAdapter.java**

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.android.myndapplication.R;
import com.example.android.myndapplication.model.User;

import java.util.List;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<User> userList;
    Dialog myDialog;



    public UserAdapter(Context mContext, List<User> userList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.userList = userList;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_list_item, parent, false);

        final ViewHolder ViewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

         ViewHolder.item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Toast.makeText(mContext, "Test Click"+String.valueOf(ViewHolder.getBindingAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         });
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        User user = userList.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(userList.get(position).getImage());
        holder.textView.setText(userList.get(position).getTitle());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private CardView item;
        private CircleImageView iv_profile;
        private TextView tv_username;
        private TextView tv_date;
        private ImageView iv_content;
        private ImageView imageView;
        private TextView textView;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_bookmarks);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_bookmarks);
            item = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_item);
            iv_profile = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_profile_image);
            tv_username = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_profile_username);
            tv_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_profile_date);
            iv_content = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_content_image);

        }
    }

}
```

**UserRecycler1.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.android.myndapplication.R;
import com.example.android.myndapplication.adapter.UserAdapter;
import com.example.android.myndapplication.model.User;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UserRecycler1 extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private UserAdapter adapter;
    private List<User> userList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        userList = new ArrayList<>();
        User user1 = new User(R.drawable.annapelzer, "Salad");
        User user2 = new User(R.drawable.brookelark_1, "Pasta");
        User user3 = new User(R.drawable.brookelark_2, "Fruit Salad");
        User user4 = new User(R.drawable.brookelark_3, "Smoothies with Fruit");
        User user5 = new User(R.drawable.cala, "Soup");
        User user6 = new User(R.drawable.davide_cantelli, "Lobster Salad");
        User user7 = new User(R.drawable.joseph_gonzales, "Breakfast toast with Berries");


        userList.add(user1);
        userList.add(user2);
        userList.add(user3);
        userList.add(user4);
        userList.add(user5);
        userList.add(user6);
        userList.add(user7);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_recycler, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler1);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2));

        adapter = new UserAdapter(getActivity(), userList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

**MainFragmentTab.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.android.myndapplication.R;
import com.example.android.myndapplication.adapter.TabAdapter;

public class MainFragmentTab extends Fragment {

    private TabAdapter adapter;
    private TabLayout tableLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs, container, false);

        viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.request_orders_view_pager);
        tableLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.request_orders_tabs);

        adapter = new TabAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new UserRecycler1(), "Public Bookmarks");
        adapter.addFragment(new UserRecycler1(), "Latest Posts");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tableLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return view;
    }
}
```

**recycler_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/profile_item">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_bookmarks"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_bookmarks"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/title2"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_green"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I hope you all can help, as I have tried for a while, but continue to receive the same output no matter what I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move your `setOnClickListener` from `onCreateViewHolder` into `onBindViewHolder`.

You might want to check [this tutorial](https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/)

**Edit**

Something like here:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public UserAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_list_item, parent, false);

    final ViewHolder ViewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    User user = userList.get(position);
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(userList.get(position).getImage());
    holder.textView.setText(userList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Toast.makeText(mContext, "Test Click"+userList.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     });

}
```

Comment: I moved it into onBindViewHolder, but now it says that: 
final ViewHolder ViewHolder = new ViewHolder(view)  - Cannot resolve symbol 'view'

Comment: You don't need that line. Just add `holder.item.setOnClickListener`

Comment: I removed that line, but now my ViewHolder.getBindingAdapterPosition()) says - Non-static method 'getBindingAdapterPosition()' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: The code now: 
 
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(userList.get(position).getImage());
        holder.textView.setText(userList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Test Click"+String.valueOf(ViewHolder.getBindingAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

Comment: Please, take a look at the tutorial or code I posted